# how to style elements in an array as a table in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I style 24 elements in an array with a table of 4 columns and 6 rows?

The array has 24 elements like this:

```js
const words = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x" ]
```

and I map them over in render method:

```
<View>
  {words.map((word, id) => (
    <View key={id}><Text>{word} </Text></View>
  ))}
</View>
```

Comment: First you'll want to chunk your array into sub-arrays of 4 each, so it looks like `[["a", "b", "c", "d"],["e", "f", "g", "h"]...` -- you can use lodash.chunk for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some simple flex properties:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  table: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  cell: {
    flexBasis: '25%',
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```

And then:

```
<View style={styles.table}>
  {words.map((word, id) => (
    <View style={styles.cell} key={id}><Text>{word} </Text></View>
  ))}
</View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/@morkadosh/mad-salsa